# Recycling a fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I am getting out of memory issue because of Bitmaps. My app is a horizontal carousel of images, which implemented with ViewPager and fragments.

So can anyone point out on how to recycle the fragment and where to do that?

Below are my codes

```
public ImageSliderFragment(){}

public void initializeEvent(OnExpeditionImageViewTouch event){
    this.event = event;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.view_pager_single_frame_layout, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    final int pos = args.getInt(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_FOR_FRAGMENT_POSITION);
    position = pos;
    expedition_image = ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stackView));
    try {
        expedition_image.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), AppConstants.imageResource.get(position), 400, 400));

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void setExitSharedElementCallback(SharedElementCallback callback) {
    super.setExitSharedElementCallback(callback);
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

PagerAdapter code

```
 private class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Map<Integer, ImageSliderFragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ImageSliderFragment imageSliderFragment = new ImageSliderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_FOR_FRAGMENT_POSITION,position);
        imageSliderFragment.setArguments(args);
        mPageReferenceMap.put(Integer.valueOf(position),imageSliderFragment);
        return imageSliderFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AppConstants.NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return /**/POSITION_NONE;//super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return  super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        //ImageSliderFragment fragment = (ImageSliderFragment)object;
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public ImageSliderFragment getFragment(int key) {
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, anyone can point out a solution for this. Because my app have bunch of images which will load asynchronously,now after few minutes on low RAM devices it just closes and releases the memory and start again.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by minor changes,

Below are the modified piece of code

In ImageSliderFragment class

```
public static ImageSliderFragment newInstance(int imageNum) {
    final ImageSliderFragment f = new ImageSliderFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_FOR_FRAGMENT_POSITION, imageNum);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

And my CustomViewPagerAdapter getItem looks like below;

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageSliderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how that solution recycles fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try this in manifest it will allocate more memory for viewpager

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: i know this, i was rather looking to recycle the view instead of increasing the Heap.

Comment: It is best way to do it and its not bad thing just try to use it till let me use your code to find the solution with large heap

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ImageView as WeakReference as mentioned in this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

```
imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
```